# Flutter: Either one of the 1st 2 conditions and either one of the 2nd 2 conditions, What's wrong with my code?

Tags: flutter, dart, if-statement

This is a validation for TextFormField(),

```
      if (value!.startsWith('http') ||
              value.startsWith('ftp') &&
          value.endsWith('jpg') || value.endsWith('png')) {
        return null;
      }
      return 'Check Again';
    },
```

Comment: `(value!.startsWith('http') || value.startsWith('fttp')) &&
(value.endsWith('jpg') || value.endsWith('png')))`

Comment: but actually its easier to use: `if (['http', 'ftp'].any(value.startsWith) && ['jpg', 'png'].any(value.endsWith)) { ` - of course if those list of schemes and file extensions became longer you can use: `if (schemes.any(value.startsWith) && fileExtensions.any(value.endsWith)) { `

Answer (score 2):

According to [operator instruction](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#operators), `&&` has higer precedence than `||`.
So your expression is equal to

```
if (...http || (...ftp && ...jpg) || ...png)`.
```

So the solution is

```
if ((...http || ...ftp) && (...jpg || ...png))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to both your or (||) conditions into () because it will check all 4 conditions at the same time.

```
if ((value!.startsWith('http') || value.startsWith('fttp')) && (value.endsWith('jpg') || value.endsWith('png')))
```

By this, it will be divided into two groups. so now it will check first grouped conditions and then main conditions like

```
if ((true || true ) && (true || false))
if (true && true)
```